# Facebook Canvas setAutoGrow grows forever in IE

Tags: facebook, css, canvas, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am seeing a weird issue in Internet Explorer 9 on my Facebook pagetab when I have setAutoGrow to true. The height grows continuously without end. This is only happening in Internet Explorer for me. Tested with Chrome and Firefox as well.

An example can be found at https://www.facebook.com/GunSweeps/app_480125662005248

Any ideas on what could be the cause? I read another thread on here that suggested it was html, body being set to 100%, and another which said a top-margin was the cause. I'm tried both of these remedies to no avail.

Edit: In more searching, I saw that a global variable might have been the issue, but went through and that does not appear to be the cause either.

Thanks ahead of time for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can Try

```
FB.Canvas.setSize();
```

After all your contents load

or use a simple timer

```
   var resizetimer= window.setTimeout(function() {
           FB.Canvas.setSize();
       }, 4000);
```